# How to read the Alignment type from the BerkeleyAligner? - Java

Tags: java, text, nlp, alignment, text-alignment

After downloading the trunk code from `http://code.google.com/p/berkeleyaligner/`, I added the project into my build path on Eclipse. Then with the code below i can extract the alignments for each sentence pair that i've read from the sourceFile and targetFile.
After the alignment, how to read the `Alignment` type from the BerkeleyAligner?

```
import edu.berkeley.nlp.wa.mt.Alignment;
import edu.berkeley.nlp.wa.mt.SentencePair;
import edu.berkeley.nlp.wordAlignment.combine.WordAlignerCombined;
public static void main(String[] args) {
BufferedReader brSrc = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("sourceFile"));
BufferedReader brTrg = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("targetFile"));
while ((currentSrcLine = brSrc.readLine()) !=null) {
    String currentTrgLine = brTrg.readline();
    // Reads into BerkeleyAligner SentencePair format.
    SentencePair src2trg = new SentencePair(sentCounter, params.get("source"),
        Arrays.asList(srcLine.split(" ")), Arrays.asList(trgLine.split(" ")));
    // Generate Alignment type from SentencePair
    WordAlignerCombined aligner;
    Alignment alignedPair = aligner.alignSentencePair(src2trg);
    // How do i print out the Alignment???
    }
}
```

e.g. sourceFile:

```
this is the first line in the textfile.
that is the second line.
foo bar likes to eat bar foo.
```

e.g. targetFile:

```
Dies ist die erste Textzeile in der Datei.
das ist die zweite Zeile.
foo bar gerne bar foo essen.
```

Comment: after some online hunting... here's some hints `http://code.google.com/p/tdx-nlp/source/browse/trunk/pa2/java/src/cs224n/assignments/WordAlignmentTester.java?r=67`. But i'm still figuring out how to call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the GIZA. [Alignment](http://code.google.com/p/berkeleyaligner/source/browse/trunk/src/edu/berkeley/nlp/wa/mt/Alignment.java) has a method for that:

```
public void writeGIZA(PrintWriter out, int idx)
```

GIZA is:

```
"# sentence pair (%d) source length %d target length %d alignment score : 0\n"
"NULL ({ %s })"
" %s ({ %s })" (englishSentence.get(i), StrUtils.join(alignments))
```

`idx` is just the sentence pair id.

`out` is just where you want to print it.